# Webscraping after ajax loaded site content

Tags: go, web-scraping

I'm trying to get colly to scrape the following page: https://www56.muenchen.de/termin/index.php?loc=BB.

Here is my code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"

    "github.com/gocolly/colly"
)

func main() {
    c := colly.NewCollector(
        colly.IgnoreRobotsTxt(),
        colly.Async(false),
    )

    c.OnHTML("html", func(e *colly.HTMLElement) {
        fmt.Println(e.Text)
    })

    c.OnError(func(_ *colly.Response, err error) {
        log.Println("Something went wrong:", err)
    })

    c.Visit("https://www56.muenchen.de/termin/index.php?loc=BB")

    c.OnScraped(func(r *colly.Response) {
        fmt.Println("Finished")
    })
}
```

The problem is that after the website is visited it loads some content. I'm unsure how to tell colly to "wait" until that has happened and then look at the result.

Looking forward to some ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can't since colly would have to do that client-side, but colly [does not execute JavaScript](https://github.com/gocolly/colly/issues/261) - so no Ajax with it.

To simulate a browser you can use selenium or phantomjs as the link above suggests.

Comment: see also nightmarejs zombiejs https://godoc.org/github.com/fedesog/webdriver https://github.com/chromedp/chromedp